# Angular 2 authentication - storing passportjs token for use

Tags: angular, express, passport.js

The following express code returns a token after redirecting a user to facebook for login and then creating a user, storing them in my database and redirecting to /auth/facebook/callback. How do I fetch this token using callbacks/promises/observables/? within my frontend client and store it in angular 2 authentication service as a local window variable in the users browser for use during the session?

```
userRouter.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function(req,res,next){
  passport.authenticate('facebook', function(err, user, info) {           
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        err: info
      });
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          err: 'Login failed'
        });
      }
      var token = Verify.getToken(user); 
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Login successful',
        success: true,
        token: token
      });
    });
  })(req,res,next);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If not using [ngrx store](https://github.com/ngrx/store), I recommend simply using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

To set:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', this.token);
```

To get:

```
localStorage.getItem('token');
```

To delete:

```
localStorage.removeItem('token');
```

This should get you started:

```
login(something: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http
        .post(this.authUrl, JSON.stringify({ }),  { headers: this.headers })
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let responseObject = response.json();        
            let token = responseObject.token;     
            localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify({ token: this.token}));
            return true; 
        });
  }
```

If you save JSON object in localStorage like in my example, you will need to parse it:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
```

Comment: Hi Frecia, this is very useful but I dont know how to actually get the token into my angular 2 app. localhost:3000/users/auth/callback?=.... is a white page with a json object that contains the token and success message returned from passportjs on the backend. How do I redirect that json object into my angular app?

Comment: I need a callback or promise or something because they have to login through facebook and then get redirected.

Comment: something like this : login(data).then((result){ console.log(result)}) should hold user data

Comment: my login button is an href which activates my passportjs facebook strategy and redirects the user to facebooks page for verification of app permissions and then redirects back to my page at /auth/facebook/callback - it is on this redirection that I need to grab the json token in my angular2 frontend and redirect them to an angular2 route. Got no idea how to do that lol